# SELECT DATA FROM A PREVIOUS LINE

Tags: postgresql

**Table:**

```
worker_id |  created_at | state_id
---------- ------------- ----------
1         | 14-6-2021   | 12
2         | 14-6-2021   | 12
3         | 13-6-2021   | 12
4         | 12-6-2021   | 12
3         | 10-6-2021   | 4
2         | 9-6-2021    | 4
4         | 8-6-2021    | 12
4         | 1-6-2021    | 4
1         | 1-6-2021    | 12
```

**What I want**

```
worker_id |  created_at | state_id
---------- ------------- ---------- 
2         | 14-6-2021   | 12
3         | 13-6-2021   | 12
```

I need to obtain the worker_id of the workers that have state_id = 12, and that comply with their previous state_id = 4. I have made multiple attempts but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please write your post in english.

To get the result you want you can use window functions and CTE.

```
with w as (
select *, lag(state_id) over (partition by worker_id order by worker_id, created_at) as previous_state
from workers
)
select * from w where previous_state = 4
```

[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8JJy6ptf95s5mrAeAKDsmD/0)